# RADIUS Server redundant MySQL

Tags: mysql, configuration, redundancy, radius

I am currently building a test setup for a RADIUS application running [FreeRADIUS V.3.xx](http://freeradius.org/)  in combination with MySQL. The entire setup is to be redundant. All servers are running on virtual machines running openSUSE 13.1

My problem is that I can't seem to find the correct configuration for redundant MySQL servers. Does anyone have experience with this ?

What I've done up until now, is basically follow the relevant portion of the official  [freeradius wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Fail-over)... tried coming up with variations using group, detail, direkt manipulation of rlm_sql_mysql socket... anything I could think of.. but without success. Currently it's back to the "wiki status"

That is:

I removed the link to **sql** from .../mods-enabled/ as that caused the redundant servers to fail even the instantiation...

File: .../radius.conf

Section: modules {...}
Added entries:

```
sql sql1{ ...#config...}
sql sql2{ ...#config...}
```

Section: instantiate {...}  Added entry:

```
redundant redundant_sql {
      sql1
      sql2
      handled
    }
```

And then added **redundant_sql** in File: .../sites-available/default    (linked to sites-enabled)

Sections: authorize {...} & post-auth{...} (I don't need accounting)

Here is some of the debug output:

Instantiation (Both sql1 and sql2 have to be accessible for the RADIUS server to start.. which is shitty but not the current problem):

```
    radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 instantiate {
 }
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_sql
  # Instantiating module "sql1" from file /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
  sql sql1 {
    driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"
    server = "**IP sql1**"
    port = "3306"
    login = "radius"
    password = <<< secret >>>
    radius_db = "radius"
    read_groups = yes
    read_clients = no
    delete_stale_sessions = yes
    sql_user_name = "%{User-Name}"
    default_user_profile = ""
    client_query = "SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas"
    authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_reply_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_group_check_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_group_reply_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}' ORDER BY id"
    group_membership_query = "SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = BINARY '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority"
    simul_count_query = ""
    simul_verify_query = "SELECT radacctid, acctsessionid, username, nasipaddress, nasportid, framedipaddress, callingstationid, framedprotocol FROM radacct WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
    safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /"
  }
rlm_sql (sql1): Creating new attribute sql1-SQL-Group
rlm_sql (sql1): Registering sql_groupcmp for sql1-SQL-Group
   accounting {
    reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}.query}"
   }
   post-auth {
    reference = ".query"
   }
   mysql {
    tls {
    }
   }
rlm_sql (sql1): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked
rlm_sql (sql1): Attempting to connect to database "radius"
rlm_sql (sql1): Initialising connection pool
   pool {
    start = 5
    min = 4
    max = 32
    spare = 3
    uses = 0
    lifetime = 0
    cleanup_interval = 30
    idle_timeout = 60
    retry_delay = 1
    spread = no
   }
rlm_sql (sql1): Opening additional connection (0)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql1): Opening additional connection (1)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql1): Opening additional connection (2)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql1): Opening additional connection (3)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql1): Opening additional connection (4)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
  # Instantiating module "sql2" from file /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
  sql sql2 {
    driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"
    server = "**IP sql2**"
    port = "3306"
    login = "radius"
    password = <<< secret >>>
    radius_db = "radius"
    read_groups = yes
    read_clients = no
    delete_stale_sessions = yes
    sql_user_name = "%{User-Name}"
    default_user_profile = ""
    client_query = "SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas"
    authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_reply_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_group_check_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}' ORDER BY id"
    authorize_group_reply_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}' ORDER BY id"
    group_membership_query = "SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = BINARY '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority"
    simul_count_query = ""
    simul_verify_query = "SELECT radacctid, acctsessionid, username, nasipaddress, nasportid, framedipaddress, callingstationid, framedprotocol FROM radacct WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
    safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /"
  }
rlm_sql (sql2): Creating new attribute sql2-SQL-Group
rlm_sql (sql2): Registering sql_groupcmp for sql2-SQL-Group
   accounting {
    reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}.query}"
   }
   post-auth {
    reference = ".query"
   }
   mysql {
    tls {
    }
   }
rlm_sql (sql2): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked
rlm_sql (sql2): Attempting to connect to database "radius"
rlm_sql (sql2): Initialising connection pool
   pool {
    start = 5
    min = 4
    max = 32
    spare = 3
    uses = 0
    lifetime = 0
    cleanup_interval = 30
    idle_timeout = 60
    retry_delay = 1
    spread = no
   }
rlm_sql (sql2): Opening additional connection (0)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql2): Opening additional connection (1)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql2): Opening additional connection (2)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql2): Opening additional connection (3)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql (sql2): Opening additional connection (4)
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
```

After stopping sql1 and sending a request this happens:

```
...#irrelevant stuff
Received Access-Request Id 36 from **IP switch**:8345 to **IP RADIUS**:1812 length 128
        User-Name = '**mac-address**'
        User-Password = '**mac-address**'
        NAS-IP-Address = **IP switch**
        NAS-Port = 3
        NAS-Port-Id = 'Port 3'
        NAS-Port-Type = Ethernet
        NAS-Identifier = '**nas name**'
        Service-Type = Call-Check
        Framed-MTU = 1500
        Called-Station-Id = '**mac-address**'
        Calling-Station-Id = '**mac-address**'
    (1) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
    (1)   authorize {
    (1)   [preprocess] = ok
    (1)     update request {
    (1) EXPAND %{tolower:%{1}%{2}%{3}%{4}%{5}%{6}}
    (1)    --> **mac-address**
    (1)     Calling-Station-Id := '"**mac-address**"'
    (1)     User-Name := '&Calling-Station-Id -> '**mac-address**''
    (1)     User-Password := '&Calling-Station-Id -> '**mac-address**''
    (1)     } # update request = noop
    (1)     [updated] = updated
    (1)    } # if (Calling-Station-Id =~ **Syntax check**  = updated
    (1)     ... skipping else for request 1: Preceding "if" was taken
    (1)   } # rewrite_calling_station_id rewrite_calling_station_id = updated
    (1) detail : EXPAND /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d
    (1) detail :    --> /var/log/radius/radacct/**IP switch**/detail-20151019
    (1) detail : /var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d expands to /var/log/radius/radacct/**IP switch**/detail-20151019
    (1) detail : EXPAND %t
    (1) detail :    --> Mon Oct 19 15:03:18 2015
    (1)   [detail] = ok
    (1)   redundant redundant_sql {
    (1) sql1 : EXPAND %{User-Name}
    (1) sql1 :    --> **mac-address**
    (1) sql1 : SQL-User-Name set to '**mac-address**'
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reserved connection (4)
    (1) sql1 : EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
    (1) sql1 :    --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id
    rlm_sql (sql1): Executing query: 'SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id'
    rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 2006, returning RLM_SQL_RECONNECT
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reconnecting (4)
    rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
    rlm_sql_mysql: Couldn't connect socket to MySQL server radius@**IP sql1**:radius
    rlm_sql_mysql: Mysql error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '**IP sql1**' (111 "Connection refused")'
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reserved connection (3)
    rlm_sql (sql1): Executing query: 'SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id'
    rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 2006, returning RLM_SQL_RECONNECT
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reconnecting (3)
    rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
    rlm_sql_mysql: Couldn't connect socket to MySQL server radius@**IP sql1**:radius
    rlm_sql_mysql: Mysql error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '**IP sql1**' (111 "Connection refused")'
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reserved connection (2)
    rlm_sql (sql1): Executing query: 'SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id'
    rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 2006, returning RLM_SQL_RECONNECT
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reconnecting (2)
    rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
    rlm_sql_mysql: Couldn't connect socket to MySQL server radius@**IP sql1**:radius
    rlm_sql_mysql: Mysql error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '**IP sql1**' (111 "Connection refused")'
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reserved connection (1)
    rlm_sql (sql1): Executing query: 'SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id'
    rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 2006, returning RLM_SQL_RECONNECT
    rlm_sql (sql1): Reconnecting (1)
    rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
    rlm_sql_mysql: Couldn't connect socket to MySQL server radius@**IP sql1**:radius
    rlm_sql_mysql: Mysql error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '**IP sql1**' (111 "Connection refused")'
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql_mysql: Socket destructor called, closing socket
    rlm_sql (sql1): Failed to reconnect (1), no free connections are available
    rlm_sql (sql1): Executing query: 'SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '**mac-address**' ORDER BY id'
    Segmentation fault
```

After destructing the last connection to sql1 I'd expect the "redundant" to kick in and sql2 to be contacted... but RADIUS aborts instead.

I know I only ** the IP and macs, but everything else will be reset properly anyway if this project graduates the "test-setup-stage".

I'd really appreciate any help as I'm kinda at the end of my rope here.

Thanks a lot if you've even read up to here!

Comment: This is the gdb output.
The RADIUS Server was started with both sql servers running.
Upon completion of initiation (ready to process) sql1 was stopped --> Fail on (0). The current redundancy setting is still as described above (l-b experiments didn't really work for me).

@Arran Cudbard-Bell: I hope this is the backtrace you meant..    
    <pre>
    <code>

Comment: #0  0x00007ffff4ab4b46 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_sql_mysql.so
#1  0x00007ffff4ab4bff in ?? () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_sql_mysql.so
#2  0x00007ffff4cbc71e in rlm_sql_select_query () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_sql.so
#3  0x00007ffff4cbc8e2 in sql_getvpdata () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_sql.so
#4  0x00007ffff4cbbb65 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/rlm_sql.so
#5  0x0000555555577eea in ?? ()
#6  0x0000555555577880 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000555555577a79 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000555555577880 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000555555577a79 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000555555578bcd in modcall ()

Comment: #11 0x000055555557629f in indexed_modcall ()
#12 0x0000555555567c9a in rad_authenticate ()
#13 0x0000555555584e67 in ?? ()
#14 0x00005555555819d6 in ?? ()
#15 0x00005555555836ec in request_receive ()
#16 0x0000555555571e0c in ?? ()
#17 0x0000555555581ed1 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007ffff79a5b8d in fr_event_loop () from /usr/lib64/freeradius/libfreeradius-radius.so
#19 0x0000555555566e86 in main ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your help Arran Cudbard-Bell!

For anyone else who has run into the same problem; using the newest tarball ([Version 3.0.10: tar.bz2 (PGP Signature)](http://freeradius.org/download.html)) and building from that includes bugfixes that solve the redundancy issue.

Also note, that the entry in the wiki is not complete. If more than one instance of sql is to be used, the following must be done in addition:

- If you were formerly running a single instance of sql, remove the sql softlink from raddb/mods-enabled/
- When configuring the sql1 and sql2 moldules write: **group_attribute = "${.:instance}-SQL-Group"** before **$INCLUDE
  ${modconfdir}/${.:name}/main/${dialect}/queries.conf"**, as the standard config will throw errors if you don't.

Though this is documented in the config files themselves, the wiki doesn't mention it.

--Thanks @ all & closed--

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in FreeRADIUS and you should open an issue ticket on the [FreeRADIUS issue tracker](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/issues) with the information you posted above, and if you can, the backtrace from running it under a debugger.

For gdb you should be able to do:

```
gdb --args <path to radiusd> -X

run
bt
```

The backtrace will show where the issue is.  I had a quick attempt at reproducing it on the v3.1.x branch, and couldn't, but that may be because the bug requires connections to be open before hand, to trigger the defect.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I've been experimenting with combining "redundant" with "load-balance" in a tree structure, which seems to work in a couple of cases. 

If all else fails I'll have to write a littel daemon running on the Rad servers that takes over the redundancy... It'd be a shame to use a workaround though.

Comment: If you submit the backtrace we can probably fix it :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't in the office for a while... 
I'm trying now :D gdb keeps returning a Python error... and as I'm not familiar with gdb it's slow going. I'm on it though.